# Can I split the channels in a two-channel op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I have this circuit:

[image]

In this circuit, I have two single-channel op-amps.

Can I just make an adapter, splitting one dual-channel op-amp into each section?

Answer (score 2):

In normal linear conditions, crosstalk between the two opamps in the same package is usually extremely low (it is mentioned in most datasheets) so it's absolutely okay to use dual/quad opamps to save space, cost and routing headaches.

However they will still couple through the power supply. Basically if you use one of the opamps in comparator mode, or make it clip a lot, and/or use a nonlinear load that causes output current spikes, then the opamp can draw distorted current from its power supply, and that can couple into the other opamp via its power supply pins. This also applies to two independent opamps, to a lesser degree. This should not be the case in this circuit.

Now I see two NE5534 opamps. These are nice, you can adjust the gain bandwidth product with the extra capacitor C74/C75 so you get higher performance when using the opamp in high gain circuits like microphone preamps. The price of this is that the opamp is not unity gain stable unless the extra capacitor is added.

However the feedback networks (C72/R100) and also the gain pot when it is set to maximum make the opamp operate at unity gain at HF. So they used 22pF for C74, which makes the opamp unity gain stable and... basically it turns it into a NE5532, which is the unity gain stable version of NE5534.

So why did they use NE5534, whose main feature is adjustable gain bandwidth, then set it to the same bandwidth as the non-adjustable NE5532? Perhaps for the lower noise (NE5534 has 3.5nV/rtHz versus 5 for the 5532).

Anyway this means you can safely use the dual opamp NE5532 and remove the compensation caps C74/C75. If you pick another dual opamp, you should pick one that is unity gain stable. It should also have a strong output stage because the load resistors are pretty low (2K pot...) ; for example TL072 would distort with this kind of load.

Answer (score 1):

A dual op-amp is just two individual op-amps in one package.  They will share power supply pins but otherwise can be used as two separate op-amps. (similarly, a Quad op-amp is four op-amps in one package.)

A single op-amp may have some extra connections (like balance) that won't be available in the multi-section packages.